# If $|G|\geq 4$ is a planar graph then there are at least 4 vertices with degree at most 5?

Tags: graph-theory

The hint given is to transform this into a triangulation and what can you say about the value of $\delta (G')?$.

So add edges to G until G' is a triangulation. Then $3|G'|-6=e(G') \Rightarrow e(G')\geq 6$

What can I say about $\delta (G')?$
I'm lost

Answer (score 2):

This approach is similar to Willard's, but I'm pretty certain that your formula is fine (you can check both of them against [some examples](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangulatedGraph.html)).

Let $n=|G|$. Then $e(G')=3n-6$.

If $G'$ is a triangulation with at least four vertices then $\delta(G') \geq 3$.

You'll probably want to show that bit rigorously, but to convince you that it's plausible:

Every vertex $v$ is in some (potentially unbounded) face of $G'-v$. That face must have at least three vertices, and $v$ must be adjacent to them in $G'$. (It's also a corollary of the $3$-connectedness of maximal planar graphs if you happen to know that fact.)

Rest of the answer:

> $6n-12=2e(G')=\sum\deg(v) \geq k\delta(G') + 6(n-k) \geq 3k + 6(n-k)$
>
>
> (I've split the sum up into the $k$ vertices of degree $\leq 5$ and the $n-k$ remaining vertices.)
>
>
> Rearranging we get $k \geq 4$.